# Categorization of Natural Language Processing Tasks

Tags: nlp

### Problem

I am currently learning basics of natural language processing. I see many tasks in this area is assigning labels to each individual words in the sentence, including POS tagging, chunking, named entity recognition and semantic role labeling.

My question is

- Are there other tasks that **do not** involve assign labels to each word in the sentence. One thing I could think of is sentiment analysis, which is assigning label to entire sentence/document or different aspects of sentence/document.
- Is there some survey that is recommended to read that summarize the general tasks in natural language processing.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, you need to know about the unsupervised learning tasks in NLP. For this, we mostly vectorize the input sentences using an embedding matrix.

**Text Summarization:**

Text Summarization not based on Neural Networks is used in a number of systems. These systems vectorize the input and then rank the sentences using a ranking algorithm ( like TextRank ) and cosine similarity based on their importance. The most important sentences are then given as output. You can read more [here](https://link.medium.com/qS7YCFVXNW).

**Similarity between two documents:**

If you have a powerful document vectorizer like [Doc2Vec](https://link.medium.com/ExRyAYsYNW), then the vectors of similar documents are similar to each other with some score. This score can be derived using cosine similarity.

> A technology blog will have a higher score of similarity with a computer science based blog rather than a holiday/tourism blog.

Such systems are useful in many use cases. [Clustering algorithms](https://link.medium.com/wkjFPRvYNW) have also been applied here.

**Sentiment Analysis is not an unsupervised learning task. It is a classification task:**

For training a sentiment analysis model, you need a dataset which consists of text and its corresponding sentiment ( categorical or binary ). Such a model could not be achieved through clustering or ranking methods. But, yes, these models use word embedding like the other models.

**Some links which describe the basic tasks categorized under NLP:**

- https://natural-language-understanding.fandom.com/wiki/List_of_natural_language_processing_tasks
- https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2017/10/essential-nlp-guide-data-scientists-top-10-nlp-tasks/
- “Deep Learning for NLP: An Overview of Recent Trends” by Elvis https://link.medium.com/iItIayc0NW
- https://blog.algorithmia.com/introduction-natural-language-processing-nlp/